# Woocommerce How to get Order item meta in client side

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on order id how to get order item meta? 
I used  product add-ons plugin for sending the item meta data from client side
The exact order item data need to display on client side:

[image: screenshot]

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$customer = new WC_Customer( $order_id );
```

based on order id I need to retrieve the order item meta for client side.

Comment: Why don't you look at the "View Order" template and see what it does?

Comment: The view order for admin hook not for client hook so that i am looking for some other way

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you use the woocommerce hook called `woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta`.

I create a custom example function to show you how it work, but if you need more [see this link](https://blackandwhiteshades.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/customize-woocommerce-admin-order-item-meta/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'lt_order_meta_customized_display',10, 3 );

/**
 * @param $item_id
 * @param $item
 * @param $product   Product
 */
function lt_order_meta_customized_display( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    /*
    *  The default key to "$all_meta_data" can be: _qty,_tax_class,_line_tax,_line_tax_data,_variation_id,_product_id,_line_subtotal, _line_total,_line_subtotal_tax
    */
    $all_meta_data = get_metadata( 'order_item', $item_id, "", "" );  
    ?>
    <div class="order_data_column" style="float: left; width: 50%; padding: 0 5px;">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Customized Values' ); ?></h4>
        <?php
            echo '<p><span style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">' . __( "Item to show 01" ) . '</span><span>:&nbsp;' . "Value to show 01" . '</span></p>';
    ?>
     </div>
<?php
}
```

***The visual result is similar to:***

[image]